# Adding gutters to foundation in Wordpress

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm starting to design a Wordpress theme from a base of Reverie which runs on Foundation 3 code. I have created themes before but I'm trying to get my head around the grid method, in particular how best to achieve gutters.

The problem:

See my test site here http://diskbacker.com/

I have the content div and sidebar div with background colors to show the issue. They touch each other by default.

1. How do I add separation between the content div and the sidebar div?
2. How do I add inside padding to content and sidebar?
3. As I'm going 'responsive' will this separation cause issues on mobile devices?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put another div inside the column works...

```
<div class="four columns">
<div style="margin:25px; background: #ccc;">test</div></div>
<div class="eight columns">eight</div>
```

You can also look for the class .panel in foundation and adapt to your specific needs:

```
.panel { background: #f2f2f2; border: solid 1px #e6e6e6; margin: 0 0 22px 0; padding: 20px; } 
.panel > :first-child { margin-top: 0; } 
.panel > :last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

Alternatively - use foundation v2

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend firstly, reading the ZURB Foundation documentation, where it explains the usage of the grid:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/grid.php

> Gutters are created simply with padding on the columns. That means
>   columns have simple widths like 25%, or 50%. Adjusting the padding
>   adjusts the gutters, and this can be controlled either through Scss
>   variables, the download customizer, or through the CSS itself.

As with any HTML/CSS site, you can identify the selector for the element you want to modify and in your custom CSS stylesheet, identify the padding for that element, e.g.:

```
.sidebar {padding:14px;}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the first thing I tried. If you have Firebug or similar you can try it on the example site, it doesn't work. Only adding padding on the child divs works (such as post-box). I want to check this is the right method before going further.